# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException while scrolling List

Tags: java, android, arrays, listview, baseadapter

```
private class listAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return labels.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {

        return getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {

        TextView name, type, time, date, location, comm, spot, spottype;
        TextView oname, oreg, otype, odate, otime, olocation;
        final ImageView pic1;
        final ImageView pic2;
        final ImageView pic3;
        ImageView ovtype, sloc;
        ImageLoadingListener animateFirstListener = new AnimateFirstDisplayListener();
        int j = 0, x = 0;
        if (convertView == null) {
            vv = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                    R.layout.other_item, null);
        } else {
            vv = convertView;
        }
        pic1 = (ImageView) vv.findViewById(R.id.pic1);
        pic2 = (ImageView) vv.findViewById(R.id.pic2);
        pic3 = (ImageView) vv.findViewById(R.id.pic3);
        name = (TextView) vv.findViewById(R.id.sname);
        type = (TextView) vv.findViewById(R.id.stype);
        time = (TextView) vv.findViewById(R.id.stime);
        date = (TextView) vv.findViewById(R.id.sdate);
        location = (TextView) vv.findViewById(R.id.slocation);
        comm = (TextView) vv.findViewById(R.id.scomm);
        // spot = (TextView) vv.findViewById(R.id.sspot);
        spottype = (TextView) vv.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        oname = (TextView) vv.findViewById(R.id.name);
        oreg = (TextView) vv.findViewById(R.id.reg);
        otype = (TextView) vv.findViewById(R.id.type);
        odate = (TextView) vv.findViewById(R.id.date);
        otime = (TextView) vv.findViewById(R.id.time);
        olocation = (TextView) vv.findViewById(R.id.location);
        ovtype = (ImageView) vv.findViewById(R.id.vtype);
        sloc = (ImageView) vv.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        oname.setText(testimonialData.get(position).getmake() + " "
                + testimonialData.get(position).getmodel());
        if (testimonialData.get(position).gettype()
                .equalsIgnoreCase("report")) {
            oreg.setText("Reg No:" + " "
                    + testimonialData.get(position).getReg());
        } else {
            oreg.setText("Ser No:" + " "
                    + testimonialData.get(position).getReg());
        }

        otype.setText(testimonialData.get(position).getRtype());
        odate.setText(dateformate(testimonialData.get(position).getdate()));
        otime.setText(testimonialData.get(position).getTime());
        olocation.setText(testimonialData.get(position).getsloc());
        comm.setText(testimonialData.get(position).getComm());
        if (testimonialData.get(position).getVtype()
                .equalsIgnoreCase("Car")) {
            ovtype.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_car);
        } else if (testimonialData.get(position).getVtype()
                .equalsIgnoreCase("Bicycle")) {
            ovtype.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_cycle);
            oreg.setText("Ser No:" + " "
                    + testimonialData.get(position).getReg());
        } else if (testimonialData.get(position).getVtype()
                .equalsIgnoreCase("MotorCycle")) {
            ovtype.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bike);
        } else {
            ovtype.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_other);
        }

        if (comm.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
            comm.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        if (olocation.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
            olocation.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            sloc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }


        String[] imageUrls = { testimonialData.get(position).getp1(),
                testimonialData.get(position).getp2(),
                testimonialData.get(position).getp3() };

        if (!imageUrls[0].isEmpty() && !imageUrls[0].equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            Updates.imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrls[0], pic1, options,
                    animateFirstListener);
            pic1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            pic1.setTag(imageUrls[0]);

            if (!imageUrls[1].isEmpty()
                    && !imageUrls[1].equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                Updates.imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrls[1], pic2,
                        options, animateFirstListener);
                pic2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                pic2.setTag(imageUrls[1]);

                if (!imageUrls[2].isEmpty()
                        && !imageUrls[2].equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                    Updates.imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrls[2], pic3,
                            options, animateFirstListener);
                    pic3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    pic3.setTag(imageUrls[2]);
                } else {
                    pic3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

            } else {
                pic2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        } else {
            pic1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            // pic2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }


        if (comm.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE
                || (pic1.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE
                        || pic2.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE || pic3
                        .getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)) {
            RelativeLayout rline = (RelativeLayout) vv
                    .findViewById(R.id.rline);
            rline.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        pic1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Fullimage.class);
                // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                // .show();
                intent.putExtra("IMAGES", String.valueOf(pic1.getTag()));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        pic2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Fullimage.class);
                intent.putExtra("IMAGES", String.valueOf(pic2.getTag()));

                // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                // .show();
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        pic3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Fullimage.class);
                intent.putExtra("IMAGES", String.valueOf(pic3.getTag()));
                startActivity(intent);

                // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "3", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                // .show();

            }
        });
        vv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (testimonialData.get(position).gettype()
                        .equalsIgnoreCase("report")) {
                    vid = testimonialData.get(position).getVid();
                    vmake = testimonialData.get(position).getmake();
                    vmodel = testimonialData.get(position).getmodel();
                    vreg = testimonialData.get(position).getReg();
                    vdate = testimonialData.get(position).getdate();
                    vtime = testimonialData.get(position).getTime();
                    vcomm = testimonialData.get(position).getComm();
                    vloc = testimonialData.get(position).getsloc();
                    vtypes = testimonialData.get(position).getVtype();
                    rtype = testimonialData.get(position).getRtype();
                    spic1 = testimonialData.get(position).getp1();
                    spic2 = testimonialData.get(position).getp2();
                    spic3 = testimonialData.get(position).getp3();
                    IsInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
                    if (IsInternetPresent == false) {
                        cd.showNoInternetPopup();
                    } else {
                        vinfo = new getvinfo().execute();
                    }

                } else {

                }
            }
        });
        return vv;

    }
}
```

above code is working. 
 but in this images are shuffling while scrolling so i have added below lines

```
    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {

        return getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        return position;
    }
```

But after adding this lines it giving java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException...

But if i remove  getViewTypeCount and  getItemViewType method then  images are shuffling while scrolling

**Update**:-
 if i set getViewTypeCount=200 then its working . so can any one tell me getViewTypeCount() is called once only ?

Comment: related post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596547/arrayindexoutofboundsexception-with-custom-android-adapter-for-multiple-views-in?rq=1

Comment: Where is the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException thrown?

Comment: I don't think returning `getCount()` in `getViewTypeCount()` is a good idea.What do you mean images are shuffling? Can you post the full code of `getView()`

Comment: have you provide various types of item view in list ?

Comment: images are shuffling like  say i have 15 rows and 5th row have 1 image but when scroll list image is set to any row + 5th row

Comment: i have added getview code

Comment: move all `findViewById` inside the `if` condition `if (convertView == null)`

Comment: findViewById inside the if condition if (convertView == null) giving null pointer

Comment: getViewTypeCount is called once?