# Android - Adapter with more than one possible row layout

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, arraylist, android-adapter

I have an `ArrayList` of Strings and I want to display them in a `ListView`, but I also want to choose **different layouts** for every single row of the `ListView` (based on some conditions I have), so what type of Adapter do I need?

I have already used a `custom CursorAdapter` and it has a newView method that let you choose the row layout for **every single entry** in the cursor, is there something like that but that works with an ArrayList?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a `BaseAdapter` for your `Listview` for this type of implementation.Your adapter class needs to extend `BaseAdapter` and override its methods. For eg- please see [This tutorial](http://www.pcsalt.com/android/listview-using-baseadapter-android/).

Also for using different layout you need to use these 2 methods

1. `public int getItemViewType(int position)`
2. `public int getViewTypeCount()`

Please refer to [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25742341/listview-with-multiple-types-of-row-layout-baseadapter-is-not-working-properly) post on SO.