# Deleting item from ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have an array: `Object[] array`, and an array adapter that extends `ArrayAdapter<Object>`.
When i try to delete from it using `adapter.remove(Object obj)` i get an `UnsupportedOperationException` exception, just as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476723/why-cant-one-add-remove-items-from-an-arrayadapter).
The provided answers suggest using an ArrayList instead. This is not an option for me. I need to stick with array. So i copied the array to another array, but without the item i want to delete. Then i just did:

```
oldArray = newArray;
```

and then called `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`.

This works fine except it doesn't refresh the screen. I need to close then reopen the screen to see the changes. Shouldn't `notifyDataSetChanged()` do the refreshing?

**edit:**

Following @MD's answer, this is what i'm doing right now:

```
controller.onRemove(id);

public void onRemove(int id) {
    int userListLength = usersArray.length;
    int j = 0;
    User[] newUserList = new User[userListLength-1];
    for(int i=0; i<userListLength; i++)
    {
        if(id != usersArray[i].getId())
        {
            newUserList[j] = new User();
            newUserList[j] = usersArray[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    usersArray = newUserList;
    //store in database
    //...
    view.getAdapter().refresh( usersArray );
}

public void refresh(User[] items)
{
    this.userArray = items;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**adapter construction:**

```
adapter = new myUserAdapter( controller.getBaseContext(), R.layout.user_row, userArrayList);
usersListView.setAdapter( adapter );
```

and in `myUserAdapter` i have:

```
private User[]  userArray;
```

**Solution:**

@MD's answer works. But I also had to override `getCount()` in the adapter:

```
@Override
public int getCount () {
    return userArray.length;
}
```

It's explained in the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596547/arrayindexoutofboundsexception-with-custom-android-adapter-for-multiple-views-in).

Comment: Maybe you need show your adapter here

Comment: please also post how you construct the `ArrayAdapter`

Comment: check again `adapter.remove(Object obj)`. This time you won't get exception. `userArrayList` is really an instance of `ArrayList`, right?

Comment: Why wouldn't i? I haven't changed anything except calling the new `refresh()` function

Comment: If you construct it with ArrayList, `add`/`remove` will work. If with array, it may init itself with a readonly list.

Comment: `userArrayList` is `User[]`

Comment: Then convert it to ArrayList! It's that simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have a way

Add refresh method in your `adapter`:

```
public void refresh(List<String> items)
{
    this.items = items;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and call from `Activity` like

```
yourAdapter.refresh(items); // items new arrayList or Array
```

Comment: Calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` this way gives an exception: AndroidRuntime(15393): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity

Comment: I think, keeping an extra `items` field in the class that extends ArrayAdapter wasn't meant by the authors

Comment: `notifyDataSetChanged()` now gives an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` somehow

Comment: OK it works now! I overridden `getCount()` in my adapter. I'll put explanation in my question.

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayAdapter` simply wraps the `List<T>` you pass to its constructor and when you call `remove()`, it calls the `remove()` method of that list.

If you pass an array instead of a list to the constructor, it converts it with `Arrays.asList()`.

```
/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param context The current context.
 * @param resource The resource ID for a layout file containing a TextView to use when
 *                 instantiating views.
 * @param objects The objects to represent in the ListView.
 */
public ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, T[] objects) {
    init(context, resource, 0, Arrays.asList(objects));
}
```

In older Android versions `Arrays.asList` returns a readonly list. That's why you get the exception

You must explicitly create an ArrayList out of your array:

```
adapter = new myUserAdapter( controller.getBaseContext(), R.layout.user_row, new ArrayList<User>(Arrays.asList(userArrayList)));
```

Comment: @AlaaM. why? Are you planning to modify that array? The adapter won't reflect the changes anyway